# Creating partners from 2 lists of dancers in java

Tags: java

I am trying to write public instance method `createParther()` that returns an instance of `Couple`. The method does its job by following these rules: one dancer in the couple must be from `aList` and the other `bList`, one dancer in the couple must be male and the other female. Neither dancer in the couple should be partnered already. If it is not possible to create a couple from amongst the unpartnered dancers, then `null` should be returned. If an instance of `Couple` is successfully created, both dancers involved in the couple should have their partnered instance variables set to `true`. I have attempted to list all the `aList` and `bList` to together, but then I didn't know to check the requirements as per above. Can anyone demostrate how this could be acheieved? This is not assignment.

```
public class FoxDancing
{
 private List<Couple> coupleList;
 private List<Dancer> aList;
 private List<Dancer> bList;

public FoxDancing()
{
   couplesList = new ArrayList<Parthers>();
   aList = new ArrayList<Dancer>();
   bList = new ArrayList<Dancer>();
}

public void fieldLists()
{
   this.addX("Simon","AList",'m');
   this.addX("Jason","AList",'m');
   this.addX("Ian","AList",'m');
   this.addX("Susan","BList",'f');
   this.addX("Helena","BList",'f');
   this.addX("Gina","BList",'f');
}
}
```

Comment: Although it's claimed that it's not, it does smell like a homework assignment.  From your `fieldLists` method it looks like `aList` always contains males and `bList` always females.  Hence a question: should `aList` instance variable really be named `maleDancers` and `bList` - `femaleDancers`?   In other words can you mix sexes in either list?  Design of this class will be different depending on the answer to this question.

Comment: Make sure you don't accidentally put a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugg in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you'd want to have a helper method like this:

```
Dancer findUnpartnered(List<Dancer> list) {
   for (Dancer d : list) {
      if (d.isUnpartnered()) {
          return d;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

This uses a ["foreach loop"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for a concise, readable iteration over all `Dancer` in the `List<Dancer>`.

Then you can write something like this:

```
Couple createCouple() {
   Dancer a = findUnpartnered(aList);
   Dancer b = findUnpartnered(bList);
   if (a == null || b == null) {
      return null;
   } else {
      a.setPartnered(true);
      b.setPartnered(true);
      return new Couple(a, b);
   }
}
```

While this should work, note that `findUnpartnered` is a `O(N)` *linear search*. If the list is of any considerable length, consider having alternative data structures, e.g. a [`Set<Dancer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) that partitions the list into unpartnered and partnered subsets.

---

#### On generics invariance

You've written the following:

```
// snippet from original code
private List<Couple> coupleList;
//...
couplesList = new ArrayList<Parthers>(); // DOES NOT COMPILE!
```

This will not compile. A `List<Partner>` (assuming this is what you meant to write) is *NOT* a `List<Couple>`. Perhaps you want a `new ArrayList<Couple>`, or if `Partner` is a subtype of `Couple`, then perhaps you want a `List<? extends Couple> coupleList`.

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number)

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics and Subtyping](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) and [More Fun With Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ - What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103)

---

#### On `enum`

You've written the following:

```
// snippet from original code
this.addX("Simon","AList",'m');
this.addX("Susan","BList",'f');
// potentially "bad" use of String and char constants!
```

I don't know much about Foxtrot dancing, but if there's a conceptual *A-list* and *B-list* , then you may consider using an `enum` instead of `String` markers `"AList"` and `"BList"`. Similarly, if there can only be *male* or *female* dancers, then `enum` would be much better than `'m'` and `'f'`.

```
enum FoxTrotter { A, B; }
enum Sex { MALE, FEMALE; }
```

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Enums](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

#### Related questions

- [Enumerations: Why? When?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363120/enumerations-why-when/)

Comment: That's more than enough to get me going. I Just needed an example. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I don't fully understand your requirements, but since it looks like `aList` is made up of males and `bList` females, this could be as simple as shuffling both lists and pairing couples up in a loop until one list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

First write dancer class, complete with all the methods you'll need. Then consider if you want to create an instance of Couple or if you just want to have a each dancer have a reference to their partner. Once you get to this point the rest should start falling into place. :D