# an integer and string in an enum class

Tags: java, enums

I have a problem regarding how can I put an integer value as well as a string in an enum class. I'm using the values of the enum to be stored in the database. What I want is something like this

```
public enum MyList {
    1,
    2,
    3,
    APPLE,
    BANANA
}
```

but i have an error in the value '1', it says

```
Syntax error on token "1", Identifier expected
```

I've searched for answers here but what I've found is they try to get the value of the enum based on the input integer from the user. What I need is to directly store the values `1`,`2`, `3`, `APPLE` and `BANANA` in the database.

Is it even possible to combine an integer and a string in an enum? Any help or suggestions would be a great help. Thanks a lot!

PS. I'm very new to programming, so it's quite hard for me to explain the problem using the correct terms. Kindly reply using simple terms! Thank you!

EDIT:

If `1` is the only integer at the said class, the error is like what I've said above. But after I added `2` and `3`, it has a red line in `public enum MyList {` and says

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Comment: Use ONE,TWO and THREE. I hopw this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990319/storing-integer-values-as-constants-in-enum-manner-in-java

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. Enums are objects, not integers or strings. Like any objects, they can optionally *wrap* other values. But you'll need to be more specific about what you need to get a helpful example.

Comment: @Kajal I'll check it! Thanks!

Comment: @shmosel noted! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html),

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be
>   a set of predefined constants.

The names of the constants must satisfy the same [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) as any variable, therefore it cannot be an integer.

The *style* convention is to write constants as uppercase with words separated by underscores.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom enum type like below ,

```
public enum MyList{

    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), APPLE("apple"), BANANA("banana");

    Object myItem;

    private MyList(Object myItem) {
        this.myItem= myItem;
    }

 public static MyList customValueOf(Object value) {
        for(MyList v : values())
            if(v.myItem.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) return v;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enums are special data types which contains only constant values in upper case like`public enum myList{
APPLE,
BANANA
}`

So all these constants are variable names which cannot start a name with number(like 1APPLE as var name, a variable can start with an alphabet or underscore). Remember how variables can be named in java.

Answer (score 2):

You might override the toString() for individual enum values that need it, like this:

```
public enum MyList {
    E1 { @Override public String toString() { return "1"; } },
    E2 { @Override public String toString() { return "2"; } },
    E3 { @Override public String toString() { return "3"; } },
    APPLE,
    BANANA
}
```

The downside is that you would always have to use `myEnumVal.toString()` to get the string representation of the enum instead of `myEnumVal.name()`.  If you need String to MyList conversions, you might add a static function like this:

```
public static MyList fromValue(String v) {
    for (MyList e: MyList.values()) {
        if (e.toString().equals(v)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enum is the kind of class with the limited number of its instances named with capital letters. Write the numbers with words out instead:

```
public enum MyList {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    APPLE,
    BANANA
}
```